# Javascript: How to check if a style is already injected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome plugin, through the background script, I inject a style this way:

```
if(!styleLeft){
    var styleLeft = document.createElement("style");
    document.head.appendChild(styleLeft);
    styleLeft.innerHTML = "a, .left-hand { cursor: wait; }";
}
```

but the if doesn't work when a style tag is already in the page. How can I look for my specific style?

Thanks.

Comment: Which one is "your specific style"?

Comment: And why do you use `styleLeft` in the if-condition, you assign to it afterwards? Please show us you whole code.

Comment: because is for a chrome plugin

Comment: @Bergi my specific style is "styleLeft"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the ID. Example:

```
if ( !!document.getElementById( 'a-long-id-that-will-never-collide' ) ) {
    var styleLeft = document.createElement("style");

    // Set the ID so that you can check for it later
    styleLeft.id = 'a-long-id-that-will-never-collide';

    document.head.appendChild(styleLeft);
    styleLeft.innerHTML = "a, .left-hand { cursor: wait; }";
}
```

Comment: Why do all this unnecessary work? Extra lookup by ID every time, setting ID than CAN collide? Solution from question itself with a single JS-side variable is almost perfect save for incorrect scope.

Comment: Because it's simple and it works without polluting the global scope. Introducing the scope matter just makes it more complicated, so I chose to answer this way. If you want to show how to play with closures, please show the code in your answer, I'll be glad to upvote it.

Comment: It polutes DOM instead, going against very good practice to separate data and presentation layers.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you declare `styleLeft` either in global scope or in any outer scope for this check. Otherwise you just throw it away at end of scope and will be creating a new, empty variable on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse `document.styleSheets` (they should be accessible in a Chrome plugin, but I am not 100% sure). If you give every style you inject a unique title, you will have an easier way finding the styles you have already injected:

```
var styleLeft = document.createElement("style");
styleLeft.setAttribute("title", "<a unique id>");
document.head.appendChild(styleLeft);
styleLeft.innerHTML = "a, .left-hand { cursor: wait; }";
document.head.appendChild(styleLeft);
```

Now the last entry of `document.styleSheets` has a .title attribute. Which you can use to see if it's one of yours.